# Yosys - ERROR: TCL interpreter returned an error: invalid command name "verilog_defaults"

Tags: tcl, yosys

I am trying to write a tcl script to read and synthesize a design. I used the following commands at the top of the tcl file and executed it with yosys -c filename.tcl.

```
verilog_defaults -add -I<path_to_include_dir>
```

**I got the following error:**

```
ERROR: TCL interpreter returned an error: invalid command name "verilog_defaults"
```

I do not get any errors when I execute the same command in yosys shell. Are these commands valid in tcl script or are there different commands for tcl scripts?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I missed importing yosys commands to tcl shell. I will mention the solution just for the reference of others who might face the same issue.

The issue was solved by putting the below import command at the top of the tcl file.

```
yosys -import
```

This instruction is mentioned in the link:
http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_tcl.html